# Google Places getting the street address only in search field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, google-places-api

How can I force return in the search field the street_number and route only? For example: [image]

In the picture above, when I select the first option, I want to show the "12300 Bermuda Road" only in the search field  and not included the city and country. Is there a way to restrict that?

I'm using NuxtJS

Comment: Yup. So I've already read the whole documentation regarding Google Places Autocomplete and I don't see anything that will solve my problem, as well as the AutocompleteService.

What I'm resorting to for now is that after the 'place_changed' is fired, I'll manually assign the street address + route to the search field. This process will have a 1-second delay in changing from full address to street address and I'm not satisfied with that.

Comment: I'm looking for something like an option in the google.maps.places.Autocomplete that will limit the returned address when choosing (not actually in the response but in the search field only)